# How to solve $y''-4y'+8y=(2x^2-3x)e^{2x}\cos(2x)+(10x^2-x-1)e^{2x}\sin(2x)$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Solve $$y''-4y'+8y=(2x^2-3x)e^{2x}\cos(2x)+(10x^2-x-1)e^{2x}\sin(2x)$$

---

I chose
$$
y_p=Axe^{(2+2i)}x
$$
Is my working right?

Comment: is this the only way? because is quite complex to differentiate three terms, for instance $$xe^{2x}(a+bx+cx^2)sin(2x)$$

Answer (score 0):

$$e^{2x}cos(2x)=\frac{e^{2x(i+1)}+e^{2x(-i+1)}}{2}$$
$$e^{2x}sin(2x)=\frac{e^{2x(i+1)}-e^{2x(-i+1)}}{2}$$
Let, $A = 2x^2-3x$ and $B=10x^2-x-1$

Then,
$$y''-4y'+8y = \frac{A+B}{2}e^{2x(i+1)}+\frac{A-B}{2}e^{2x(-i+1)}$$

Let $y = y_h+y_1+y_2$, where,
$$y_1''-4y_1'+8y_1=\frac{A+B}{2}e^{2x(i+1)}$$
$$y_2''-4y_2'+8y_2=\frac{A-B}{2}e^{2x(-i+1)}$$
$$y_h''-4y_h'+8y_h=0$$

For $y_i$, try solutions of the form $y_i = g(x)e^{\gamma x}$.
Then, 
$$y_i'=(\gamma g+g') e^{\gamma x}$$
$$y_i''=[\gamma(\gamma g+g')+(\gamma g'+g'')]e^{\gamma x}=[\gamma^2g + 2\gamma g'+g'']e^{\gamma x}$$

Since linear combinations of $A$ and $B$ are second order polynomials, it is reasonable to try $g = ax^2 +bx+c$.  Plug into the equation above and solve for the variables $a$, $b$, and $c$ for each $y_i$.