# undetermined coefficient

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Solve $$y''-4y'+8y=(2x^2-3x)e^{2x}\cos(2x)+(10x^2-x-1)e^{2x}\sin(2x)$$

for the left side, $$y_h(x)=C_1e^{2x}\cos(2x)+C_2e^{2x}\sin(2x)$$
for the right side, $$\Big((2x^2-3x)-(10x^2-x-1)i\Big)e^{(2+2i)x}$$

I choose $$y_p=Axe^{(2+2i)x}$$ Is this right?

Comment: Was the comment in this identical post not sufficient: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1965328/solve-odequation?

Answer (score 1):

I think that life would have been easier if, from the very beginning, we let $y=z e^{2x}$ which reduces the differential equation to become
$$z''(x)+4 z(x)=\left(2 x^2-3 x\right) \cos (2 x)+\left(10 x^2-x-1\right) \sin (2 x)\tag 1$$ Looking at the rhs, the particular solution is something like $$z(x)=P(x) \cos(2x)+Q(x)\sin(2x)$$ in which $P,Q$ have to be polynomials of degree $2$ or, more likely, $3$.

So, consider $$P(x)=a+b x+c x^2+dx^3 \qquad Q(x)=e+f x+g x^2+hx^3$$ and replace in $(1)$. Grouping terms will give $$0=(2 c+4f+ (6 d+8 g+3)x+(12 h-2) x^2) \cos(2x)+(2 g+1-4 b+x (-8 c+6 h+1)+(-12 d-10) x^2)\sin(2x)$$ and now cancel all terms to get as equations $$2c+4f=0$$ $$6 d+8 g+3=0$$ $$12 h-2=0$$ $$2 g+1-4 b=0$$ $$-8 c+6 h+1=0$$ $$-12 d-10=0$$ which are quite simple to solve (even using successive eliminations). This should give you the values of $b,c,d,f,g,h$, $a$ and $b$ being "absorbed" by the coefficients $c_1,c_2$ of the solution of the homogeneous problem.

Comment: what about equation of Yp?